# How to calculate points on the path?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a an array of latitude/longitude points, which are forming path.

[image]

Above path is consisting of 5 points. What I want is to create a function which will take some speed value and each time I call that function it will return new advanced point, based on speed. No need to smooth corners or something, just to get points on the given path.

[image]

Need some help in creating such function...

Comment: For P0 and P1: `yj= m * xj + h` with `m = ((y1-y0)/(x1-x0))` and `h` probably being the smallest `yi` you have.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Comment: @L.B: Heavy stuff as the OP states: "*No need to smooth corners*".

Comment: Background to my comment above: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation (german version, as per the map's location: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineare_Interpolation#Lineare_Interpolation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the bearing of the angle of a set of two points.

```
var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
        Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg();
```

Then calculate "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point"

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                     Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

More info available here, http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
I think you need to use radians for the angle inputs.

Comment: yep, that's exactly how I completed this while waiting for reply... thx

Comment: @Pablo If you have your answer you should be a good user and close your question, accept my answer or post your own and accept that.